# When are homotopy categories of model categories closed modules over the homotopy category of $(\infty, 1)$-categories?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, modules, infinity-categories, enriched-category-theory

Let $\mathrm{Quillen}$ be the model category of simplicial sets with the Quillen model structure, and $\mathrm{Joyal}$ the model category of simplicial sets with the Joyal model structure.

As is well-known, given an arbitrary model category $\mathcal C$, its homotopy category $h\mathcal C$ is naturally a closed module over the category of spaces, the homotopy category $h\mathrm{Quillen}$ of $\mathrm{Quillen}$.

On the other hand, the category $h\mathrm{Joyal}$, the homotopy category of $\mathrm{Joyal}$, that is the category of (small) $(\infty, 1)$-categories, is naturally a closed module not only over $h\mathrm{Quillen}$ but also over itself, $h\mathrm{Joyal}$.

My question is the following: What nice property makes a model category $\mathcal C$ into one such that its homotopy category is naturally a closed model over $h\mathrm{Joyal}$, so that, in particular, its mapping spaces can naturally be viewed as $(\infty, 1)$-categories?

Of course, the construction should give back the closed module structure over $h\mathrm{Joyal}$ in case of the category of $(\infty, 1)$-categories.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+simplicial+sets#joyals_model_structure for the people like me who haven't heard of the joyal model structure

Comment: Well, one sufficient condition is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a model category enriched over $\mathbf{sSet}_\mathrm{Joyal}$. This is the case for $\mathbf{sSet}_\mathrm{Joyal}$ itself.

Comment: Model categories enriched over SSet with the Quillen model structure are presentations of (infinity,1)-categories.  Model categories enriched over SSet with the Joyal model structure are presentations of (infinity,2)-categories.  See Remark 0.0.4 in [Jacob Lurie, (Infinity,2)-Categories and the Goodwillie Calculus I], http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0462.

Comment: Always, since the identity on underlying categories is a left Quillen functor from Joyal's to Quillen's and induces a product preserving functor on homotopy categories.

Comment: @Muro You won't get the natural closed module structure over $h\mathrm{Joyal}$ in the case of $\mathrm{Joyal}$.

Comment: @MarcNieper-Wißkirchen I didn't notice that requirement.

Comment: @Muro I didn't spell it out. Added it.

Comment: Anyway, then the natural requirement (in my opinion) is that C be a Joyal-model category in the sense of Hovey.

Comment: Could you give me link to Hovey's definition of a Joyal-model category?

Comment: Hovey defines enriched model categories in his textbook. This is a special case (which he does not address – but then again, the Joyal model structure wasn't well known when it was written!).

Comment: @MarcNieper-Wißkirchen, it's exactly what Zhen Lin says, there's nothing special about Joyal.

Comment: This is too strong for being what I would call a natural condition. Every homotopy category of a simplicial model category (one that is enriched over $\mathrm{Quillen}$) can easily be seen to be a closed module over $h\mathrm{Quillen}$. But the surprising (?) fact is that every (simplicial or not) model category's homotopy category is a closed module over $h\mathrm{Quillen}$.

Comment: The notion of 'model category' is not perfect. All of them should morally be simplicial, and to a certain extent they are (the homotopy enrichment, Quillen equivalences with simplicial models, etc.) So I wouldn't say that lifting the enrichment to models is a very strong condition.

Comment: Insofar as every (left proper, combinatorial) model category is Quillen equivalent to a simplicial one, I would compare it to the fact that, for example, every monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one. So one could call a Quillen equivalent simplicial model category a strictification of the original model category.

As in the case of monoidal categories, I think it also makes sense to study the non-strict versions (or presentations). So I can rephrase my question as follows: What is a good property that makes a model category Quillen equivalent to one enriched over $\mathrm{Joyal}$?

Comment: @Marc, the issue is that Quillen equivalence is a LOT weaker than equivalence as categories. Two model categories can be Quillen equivalent but be very far apart. There should be a much weaker condition than combinatorial to be able to say that a model category is Quillen equivalent to a simplicial one (e.g. Top is not combinatorial) but that's not known. So trying the same program with Joyal instead of sSet seems unlikely to work.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this will answer your question, but it may at least point you in the right direction (or at least some direction).

Let me start with some classical background.
Let $C$ be a category with a class of weak equivalences $W$.
Dwyer and Kan showed that this data presents an (∞,1)-category $C[W^{-1}]$, called the hammock localization.
Like the classical Gabriel-Zisman localization, its 1-morphisms are equivalence classes of zig-zags of morphisms of $C$, but it also encodes the data of homotopies between these morphisms.
From this perspective, the data of a model structure on $C$, with class of weak equivalences $W$, can be viewed as a computational tool whose purpose is to ensure that the mapping spaces of the hammock localization have a much more tractable description via taking resolutions in the Reedy model structure on simplicial objects in $C$ (at least under combinatorial and properness assumptions).

Barwick and Kan have built on the work of Dwyer-Kan to show that the (∞,1)-category of pairs $(C,W)$, called relative categories, is in fact equivalent to the (∞,1)-category of (∞,1)-categories.
Further, they have developed a model for (∞,n)-categories called *relative n-categories*.
In the case n=2, if I understand correctly, a 2-relative category is the data of a tuple $(C, W, V_1, V_2)$, where $W$, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subcategories of the category $Arr(C)$ of morphisms of $C$, subject to various axioms.
This data should be thought of as two relative categories $(V_1, W)$, $(V_2, W)$, with an ambient category $Arr(C)$ encoding relations between them.
See [C. Barwick, D. M. Kan, *n-relative categories: a model for the homotopy theory of n-fold homotopy theories*, [pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1741495/papers/nrelcats.pdf)].

Now to your question.
Since 2-relative categories present (∞,2)-categories, there is a *mapping (∞,1)-category* (instead of just a mapping (∞,0)-category = space) between any two objects.
The story of relative categories and model categories suggests that there should be a notion of 2-model category, which is some additional structure on a 2-relative category, giving a simpler description of these mapping (∞,1)-categories.
Presumably, this structure would be something like compatible model structures on the relative categories $(C,W)$, $(V_1,W)$ and $(V_2,W)$.
In other words, I think it is reasonable that, in order for a given model category to be enriched over (∞,1)-categories, one should not ask for some property, but rather for some additional structure on it, along the lines of a 2-model structure.

Comment: Hovey's book finishes with a list of Vistas, and introducing the correct notion of a 2-model category was a top priority. That was in 1998 and many people have tried to find a good definition. As far as I know, no one has succeeded. Everyone knows what the weak equivalences should be, but not the (co)fibrations. I would not advise this approach.

Comment: @DavidWhite, the question of Hovey is about model structures on 2-categories, not about model structures on 2-relative categories.  How is it relevant to this discussion?